# Cloning my Windows boot drive--Windows hangs on booting off new drive

Tags: boot, gparted, windows-backup

I copied my Windows XP partition to a new drive using GParted live CD (using the GUI).  I made sure to flag it as boot, and then used my XP disc to enter Recovery Console and ran fixboot and fixmbr on it.
Now, it will boot up to the Windows flash screen, but hangs at that point.  Any suggestions on how to proceed?
I am just trying to come up with a quick way to clone my system and make the drive bootable, and gParted seemed like the easiest way, but now I've been working on it for over an hour.

Comment: Was this a home built PC or a Dell, HP etc?

Comment: How long did you let it hang, I have seen this and left it for over 20 minutes until windows go things sorted out, came back later and it was at the desktop.

Comment: This was a home build.  Sorry for the delay, my email just now let me know there were responses =)  I did let it hang for a good 20-30 minutes.  I'll try once more.

Answer (score 2):

hm... I've never done this with GPartEd. You might want to give [ping](http://ping.windowsdream.com/ping.html) a try, it's my favorite tool for all things drive imaging.

Comment: I second Moab.  I will check that out!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, I've used WinClone with success.  If you're on a PC, I've used Norton's Ghost and Acronis True Image with success.  jcrawfordor's suggestion (ping) looks pretty cool.  I think you could also just use dd.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a drivers or paths issue. Maybe try to fix it hitting f8 (usually just the instant the beep sounds, tap it several times) so you can access the boot menu and boot in safe mode. Then try to fix once windows loaded so.(ie, disabling some hardware device, etc, to isolate the problem)

You used fixboot and fixmbr, so, should not be a problem...But remember XP installs its boot stuff always in C, despite in which partition you did install Windows XP folder.

Anyway, I have heard nice things about [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org), for these matters.

Answer (score 0):

The drive you copied to happen to be a Western Digital "EARS" (4KB sector size) drive perhaps?
(Don't know if that matters, but thought I'd ask.)

Comment: It is a WD Caviar SE16 model WD 2500 KS.  I'm not able to find specs on sector size..